# How to use OpenResty (nginx) to reduce data access time

Tags: nginx, openresty

I need to use nginx to proxy to different backend server according to the configuration information in database. One way is to use another program to write data in Redis and using [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) to access data in Redis.

To reduce access time, is there a better way to access data such as storing data in local memory using OpenResty and access that data in local memory?

Answer (score 0):

OpenResty has build-in [key-value storage](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict). All data is shared between nginx workers by shared memory, so it is notably faster than accessing Redis.

It is possible to load all required values in [init_by_lua*](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#init_worker_by_lua).

Probably you will need to use some cosocket-based library to access the database, cosocket API is disabled in 
[init_worker_by_lua*](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#init_worker_by_lua), but you may fire a timer with zero delay as [workaround](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#cosockets-not-available-everywhere).

To avoid redundant database polling by multiple nginx workers you may start the timer for the [first nginx worker](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxworkerid) only, when `ngx.worker.id == 0`.

This approach, of course, works only with static configuration data. I use it in a number of projects.